# load page with only error value with PHP

Tags: javascript, php, html, css, exit

i'm writing my own CMS in php and can't find way how to load only error when it appear. I have this kind of check

```
(isset($opt['theme']) && $opt['theme'] != "" ? "" : exit("Please Map Load Theme"));
```

But this is brief of code is from module, which is loaded after head and in head CMS load's all javascript && css libraries. so now because of Javascript i can't see this exit error code some element hide's it. does php have some function when i call it removes all loaded data and will show only that output which i will write on error.

Comment: I think that you want to clean the whole screen and only show one message, am I right?

Comment: What the actual hell does this code do?

Comment: @M4R1KU yes exactly

Comment: @PhiterFernandes it checks if isset this kind of array value it will continue code if not it will stop and tells you error

Comment: also you can't put exit in ternary. You can't execute functions in ternary, unless they only return stuff.

Comment: @PhiterFernandes: _“also you can't put exit in ternary”_ – yes, you can. The parts just have to be valid expressions.

Comment: What is in before your code that you are showing?

Comment: You could use output buffering - and then throw all current buffer content away, if such an error occurs.

Comment: Also using die or exit is not really what you should do. It's poor design.

Comment: @M4R1KU so i can't do this with any  native  php function?

Comment: @Dest you can do that with native PHP functions but not that easy as you have it now.
Take a look at output buffering as CBroe already mentioned.
[Output buffering in PHP](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.outcontrol.php)

Answer (score 0):

I can't give you an exact answer for your CMS but I can give you an idea how you could use output buffering.

If you have a template where your Site content is in it (without menu, navbar and footer). You could for example change the template to an error template if you received an error anywhere.

I used it like this in one of my projects.

```
ob_start();
if (file_exists($this->template)) {
    $this->_content = file_get_contents($this->template);
} else {
    $this->_content = file_get_contents('../path/to/error/template.php');
}
include_once('../path/to/layout.php');
$this->body = ob_get_clean();
```

I know it's not the perfect answer for your problem but i hope i could give you an idea how you could get on with this problem.

My layout file contains a part where it "[evals](http://php.net/manual/en/function.eval.php)" the code in it self. So the content of the layout file is executed and inside the layout which contains the header and footer.

Take also a look at some MVC-Frameworks. They can give you a good approach.
I oriented myself to CakePHP.